# Pure MEA vs Aqueous MEA Solution for CO2 Scrubbing

Tags: reaction-control

I was wondering if using pure MEA (Monoethanolamine) or a MEA solution using water would be a better solution for scrubbing $\ce{CO_2}$.

[image]

Based on this image, I would think the key reaction would be able to occur with both pure MEA and an MEA solution. However, in this reaction, it takes 2 amines to react with one molecule of $\ce{CO_2}$. The other reaction involves water, so I don't think it would be able to take place with pure MEA. It seems to only use 1 amine to react with one molecule of $\ce{CO_2}$, so theoretically it would would increase the $\ce{CO_2}$:MEA ratio, but I don't know the magnitude of that reaction compared to the main one.

So, it seems that having an aqueous MEA solution might improve efficiency. But the issue with an aqueous solution is that when the MEA is heated to release the CO2, it is above the boiling point of water, so the water would have to be replenished. Therefore, I would like to use pure MEA.

Ultimately, my quesion is:

Is it reasonable to use MEA as a pure liquid rather than in an aqueous solution?

Comment: If pure MEA would work OK, it would be used. It's less polar solvent without water and, perhaps counter-intuitively, less basic, afaict.